# MS Access VBA add email link to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, ms-access, hyperlink

I have an Access database that exports data to a spreadsheet.  One column contains email addresses which I would like to be clickable links to the email address from a database table.  Currently the lines of code that do this look like this:

```
    sCell1 = "B" & iRow
    xlSheet.Cells(iRow, 2) = ![Email]
    sEmail = "mailto:" & ![Email] 
    xlSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(sCell1), Address:=sEmail
```

![Email] is the email field from the relevant table.

This successfully adds the email address into the cell as a hyperlink, however, mailto: disappears and just the contents of the ![Email] field are placed in the cell.  Clicking the link in Excel produces 'The address of this site is not valid'.  I've tried various modifications to the address, adding single quotes, enclosing it in HTML <a /a>, etc. nothing seems to give the cell the necessary mailto: to launch an email package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this from Access, but please try

```
sCell1 = "B" & iRow
xlSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xlSheet.Range(sCell1), Address:="mailto:" & Email, TextToDisplay:=Email
```

If you are using late-binding you might need to use

```
sCell1 = "B" & iRow
xlSheet.Hyperlinks.Add xlSheet.Range(sCell1), "mailto:" & Email, , , Email
```

Comment: Thanks JohmM, that's brilliant, solved the problem. Both examples you provided worked.

Comment: Happy to have helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you then please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the grey check / tick icon next to it. This helps future readers know that the question has an answer and also helps to keep the focus on the questions that are not yet answered.